# Quickbooks (PHP) sdk, CustomersFindAll sample giving me random data

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

This is my first time using quickbooks php sdk, i am trying to see how every sample behaves in this sdk though when i test it with an account that i created I want to grab all costumers and it doesn't give me data from the account but like some 30 randoms costumers and names that are not in my account.

I need some help , i have put my realmid in the App.config and costumer key and others, i have also put that data in and sdk.config though the outputs still the same, i do not know whats wrong.

**ANSWER**

I found out that i was using my development keys which works only with sandbox. I fixed the problem using the production keys which work with real accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i was using my development keys which works only with sandbox. I fixed the problem using the production keys which work with real accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the root of the issue in your application logic. For me getting customers works correct. I suggest to avoid using app.config and configure QBO from code - at least for debugging.

request :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<IntuitBatchRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <BatchItemRequest bId="bID1">
    <Query>select *  FROM Customer StartPosition 1 MaxResults 1000</Query>
  </BatchItemRequest>
</IntuitBatchRequest>
```

response:

```
{
"BatchItemResponse" : [{
        "QueryResponse" : {
            "Customer" : [{
                    "Taxable" : false,
                    "Job" : false,
                    "BillWithParent" : false,
                    "Balance" : -7291.08,
                    "BalanceWithJobs" : -7291.08,
                    "CurrencyRef" : {
                        "value" : "USD",
                        "name" : "United States Dollar"
                    },
                    "PreferredDeliveryMethod" : "None",
                    "domain" : "QBO",
                    "sparse" : false,
                    "Id" : "1",
                    "SyncToken" : "3",
                    "MetaData" : {
                        "CreateTime" : "2014-12-18T13:59:34-08:00",
                        "LastUpdatedTime" : "2015-07-14T05:36:23-07:00"
                    },
                    "FullyQualifiedName" : "bob",
                    "DisplayName" : "bob",
                    "PrintOnCheckName" : "bob",
                    "Active" : true,
                    "PrimaryEmailAddr" : {
                        "Address" : "xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx"
                    }
                }, {
                    "Taxable" : false,
                    "Job" : false,
                    "BillWithParent" : false,
                    "Balance" : 0,
                    "BalanceWithJobs" : 0,
                    "CurrencyRef" : {
                        "value" : "USD",
                        "name" : "United States Dollar"
                    },
                    "PreferredDeliveryMethod" : "None",
                    "domain" : "QBO",
                    "sparse" : false,
                    "Id" : "2",
                    "SyncToken" : "1",
                    "MetaData" : {
                        "CreateTime" : "2014-12-31T10:45:46-08:00",
                        "LastUpdatedTime" : "2016-07-19T11:06:18-07:00"
                    },
                    "FullyQualifiedName" : "Manual",
                    "DisplayName" : "Manual",
                    "PrintOnCheckName" : "Manual",
                    "Active" : true,
                    "PrimaryEmailAddr" : {
                        "Address" : "Max@Max.Max"
                    }
                }, {
                    "Taxable" : false,
                    "Job" : false,
                    "BillWithParent" : false,
                    "Balance" : 0,
                    "BalanceWithJobs" : 0,
                    "CurrencyRef" : {
                        "value" : "USD",
                        "name" : "United States Dollar"
                    },
                    "PreferredDeliveryMethod" : "None",
                    "domain" : "QBO",
                    "sparse" : false,
                    "Id" : "4",
                    "SyncToken" : "0",
                    "MetaData" : {
                        "CreateTime" : "2015-04-28T03:29:32-07:00",
                        "LastUpdatedTime" : "2015-04-28T03:29:32-07:00"
                    },
                    "FullyQualifiedName" : "s1",
                    "DisplayName" : "s1",
                    "PrintOnCheckName" : "s1",
                    "Active" : true
                }
            ],
            "startPosition" : 1,
            "maxResults" : 3
        },
        "bId" : "bID1"
    }
],
"time" : "2016-07-19T15:08:35.713-07:00"
```

}

Comment: Thanks this helped me though my problem was that i was looking outputs that weren't in my account and i didn't know where it came from.